# Installing Pytables, error in finding HDF5 installation

Tags: python, hdf5, pytables

I am trying to install Pytables in Windows7 and I keep getting the following error even though I have setup the required  environment variables.

```
ERROR:: Could not find a local HDF5 installation. You may need to explicitly
state where your local HDF5 headers and library can be found by setting the
HDF5_DIR environment variable or by using the --hdf5 command-line option.
```

Is there a better way to handle this?

Comment: How did you set the environment variable? Also, did you try the `--hdf5` command line option as well?

Comment: I set the environment variable through the Advance System Settings option. And I did not try the command line option. I am not sure how to do that.

Comment: What command did you enter (and where did you enter it) to get this error message? The [PyTable doc](http://www.pytables.org/docs/manual-2.0.4/ch02.html) says to use `set` to set the environment variable or alternatively you can use the `--hdf5` option on the `setup.py` command line.